# How to Scrollback in an SSH Session from OSX (remote) to Windows (Host)?

Tags: macos, ssh

When I enter an ssh session using 'Terminal' I am unable to scrollback. Changing the scrollback buffer doesn't help.

I have a MacBook so I don't have 'Page up/down' and using 'CTRL + A' doesn't work, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can do this on my imac using the shift and page up/down keys quite happily.  The page up/down are the two right most keys in the block directly above the cursor keys. (They look like an elongated up/down arrow with markings toward one end).

This might be equivalent to using shift & command & [uparrow/downarrow] on macbook keyboard, although this link might help you more : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1569297

Comment: Freudian, it doesn't work while i'm in an ssh session. Once the ssh session starts, i'm unable to scroll.

Comment: I broke my wireless keyboard out in the hope that it'd be the same as the macbook one - with this, in a ssh session I can page up / down using Fn & uparrow/downarrow.  If this doesnt work, i'll just remove my answer.